# Convert Javascript variable into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

so I would like to now if is there any way to pass Javascript variable into PHP. I'm making a script to get location from website and I want to insert this location into MySQL to get some analytic data.

Here is my Javascript function:

```
function getPosition(position)
{
  const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  const geoApiUrl = 'https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}';
  fetch(geoApiUrl)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    position = data.city
    console.log(position)
  })
}
```

and I want to pass `position` into PHP. This function is called on page load.

I tried using express but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Make another `fetch` request.

Comment: [Many many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=send+javascript+variable+to+php+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To pass JavaScript variables into PHP and insert them into a MySQL database, you can use AJAX to send the data to a PHP script on the server.

On the client side, use JavaScript to get the location data (latitude and longitude).
Fetch the city data using an external API like https://api.bigdatacloud.net.
Once you have the city data, make an AJAX POST request to a PHP script on the server.
In the PHP script, access the location data from the $_POST superglobal and insert it into the MySQL database using PDO or MySQLi.
Here's a concise code example:

```
async function getPosition(position) {
  try {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    const geoApiUrl = `https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}`;

    const geoResponse = await fetch(geoApiUrl);
    const geoData = await geoResponse.json();

    const city = geoData.city;

    const postData = {
      latitude,
      longitude,
      city
    };

    const phpUrl = 'insert_location.php';
    const response = await fetch(phpUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    });

    const result = await response.text();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  }
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
```

PHP (insert_location.php):

```
    <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  try {
    $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $latitude = $postData['latitude'];
    $longitude = $postData['longitude'];
    $city = $postData['city'];

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=your_mysql_host;dbname=your_mysql_database", 'your_mysql_username', 'your_mysql_password');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO location_data (latitude, longitude, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute([$latitude, $longitude, $city]);

    echo 'Location data inserted successfully.';
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
```